# Render to half float texture

Tags: opengl-es

In OpenGL ES 2.0
Can I render to a RGBA texture with 16bit(half float) per channel?
Assuming that device supports OES_texture_half_float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*OES_texture_half_float* let you use texture, but not as render target. In other words, you can't write to it. 
To render to  RGBA texture with 16bit channel in OpenGL ES 2.0 you also need

> EXT_color_buffer_half_float

extension.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Or at least it looks optional for an implementation to support it. The [extension spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt) does not talk about it. Since this format became standard in ES 3.0, that spec looks like a good indication of how the extension worked in ES 2.0. In section 3.8.3, RGBA16F is listed under "texture-only color formats", and table 3.12 does not have a checkmark in the "color-renderable" column for it.